# Add another column to dataframe defining the label of multiple values by one label to plot grouped bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 3 dataframes of Standard Error of 4 different model:

```
Dataset<- c("MO", "IP", "MP","CC")
SEMONPP<-c(0.10,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.11,0.15,0.16,0.13,0.16,0.08,0.09)
SEIPNPP<-c(0.14,0.07,0.14,0.10,0.11,0.12,0.12,0.09,0.12,0.14,0.12)
SEMPNPP<-c(0.14,0.07,0.14,0.10,0.11,0.14,0.13,0.09,0.12,0.15,0.13)
SECCNPP<-c(0.14,0.07,0.14,0.11,0.12,0.14,0.12,0.10,0.13,0.14,0.14)
```

I combine the rows of dataframes of the means of NPP and SE by

```
    df <- bind_rows("df1" = df1, "df2" = df2, "df3" = df3, "df4"=df4, .id = "groups")
df$SE <- c(SEMONPP,SEIPNPP,SEMPNPP,SECCNPP)

> df
   groups zone      mean   SE
1     df1    1 0.9378712 0.10
2     df1    2 2.4830645 0.09
3     df1    3 0.7191759 0.09
4     df1    4 1.3030844 0.09
5     df1    5 1.2497096 0.11
6     df1    6 0.7247015 0.15
7     df1    7 0.1776825 0.16
8     df1    8 1.4755258 0.13
9     df1    9 1.0902742 0.16
10    df1   10 0.2679057 0.08
11    df1   12 0.7677998 0.09
12    df2    1 1.2728942 0.14
13    df2    2 1.3189574 0.07
14    df2    3 1.0934750 0.14
15    df2    4 1.3024298 0.10
16    df2    5 1.3029797 0.11
17    df2    6 1.0878356 0.12
18    df2    7 0.5390098 0.12
19    df2    8 1.2761170 0.09
20    df2    9 1.1395524 0.12
21    df2   10 0.6863418 0.14
22    df2   12 1.1534048 0.12
23    df3    1 1.2963668 0.14
24    df3    2 1.3032349 0.07
25    df3    3 1.1302980 0.14
26    df3    4 1.3049038 0.10
27    df3    5 1.3221782 0.11
28    df3    6 1.0464710 0.14
29    df3    7 0.4997006 0.13
30    df3    8 1.2777002 0.09
31    df3    9 1.1480874 0.12
32    df3   10 0.6844529 0.15
33    df3   12 1.1593346 0.13
34    df4    1 1.2819611 0.14
35    df4    2 1.4276992 0.07
36    df4    3 1.1061886 0.14
37    df4    4 1.3572913 0.11
38    df4    5 1.3588146 0.12
39    df4    6 1.1318426 0.14
40    df4    7 0.5321167 0.12
41    df4    8 1.3701237 0.10
42    df4    9 1.1996266 0.13
43    df4   10 0.6977050 0.14
44    df4   12 1.2620727 0.14
```

The zone represents different landcover classes.

How can I add a another column defining in df that df1 values (from 1 to 12) belong to MO, df2 values belong to IP, df3 values belong to MP and df4 values belong to CC? As I would like to plot a bar group, currently i use this code:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(zone = factor(zone,labels = c("EN","EB","DN","BF","F","Crub","hrub","Wv","av","rass","rop"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=zone, y=mean, fill = groups))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(.8))  +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=groups, ymin=mean-SE, ymax=mean+SE), width=0.4, position = position_dodge(.9))+
  ggtitle("")+scale_fill_manual(labels = c("MO", "IP", "MP","CC"),values=cbp1)+
  labs(y= an, x = "")+theme_bw()+theme(legend.title =element_blank())+
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=11),axis.text.y=element_text(size=11.5),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=11.5),axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the names of the first `Dataset` vector to be another column in your final dataframe. If so, this should do it:

```
modelNmae = lapply(Dataset,function(x){
                   rep(x,length(SEMONPP))
                }) %>% unlist

df = cbind(df,modelName)
```